# Как создать обёртку с try/catch для методов С#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

У меня есть множество методов в разных репозиториях с таким кодом:

```
await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("Transaction");
try
{
    // какая-то функциональность, например, обновление модели в базе или её создание
}
catch (Exception)
{
    await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("Transaction");
    return default;
}
```

Эти try/catch занимают очень много места. Возможно ли как-то их вынести, чтобы они автоматически применялись к методу?

Пробовал сделать с атрибутом, но как я понял, атрибуты нужны для какой-то мета информации, а не для функциональности.

Comment: Можно, сделайте метод, или что-то, что вам надо, и принимайте в нем `Action` или `Func`, их и вызывайте в `try`.

Comment: С атрибутом можно сделать. Для этого нужно взять какой-нибудь Compile-time AOP tool, наподобие PostSharp или Fody. Например, [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody) (там в примере как раз транзакция) или [MethodDecorator.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/MethodDecorator).

Comment: Если АОП заинтересует, то советую книгу AOP in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим это так

```
async Task<T> SomeMethodAsync(SomeArgs args)
{
    await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("Transaction");
    try
    {
        // ...
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("Transaction");
        return default;
    }
}
```

Тогда можно сделать метод таким

```
async Task<T> SomeMethodAsync(SomeArgs args)
{
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

А обертку вот так

```
async Task<T> TransactionAsync(Func<SomeArgs, Task<T>> func, SomeArgs args)
{
    await using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    await transaction.CreateSavepointAsync("Transaction");
    try
    {
        return await func(args);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackToSavepointAsync("Transaction");
        return default;
    }
}
```

А вызывать так

```
var result = await TransactionAsync(SomeMethodAsync, args);
```

Можно сделать эту обертку обобщенной, чтобы не зависеть от конкретных типов.